# How to restrict an Interface to certain IPs and Ports with iptables?

Tags: iptables

I'd like to restrict an interface (eth2) on my Linux based router to certain IPs and ports. eth1 is mainly unrestricted.

- The router does DHCP, so I'd like to allow those.
- The router does NATing.
- The router does not NTP, so I'd like to allow this to any IP.
- The router does not DNS, so I'd like to allow this to any IP.
- The devices behind the interface eth1 shouldn't have any restrictions on talking to the internet
- The devices behind the interface eth2 should only be allowed to talk to certain internet IPs

My config currently looks like this:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
# eth1 is 192.168.1.0/24, eth2 is 192.168.2.0/24, so I forward 192.168.0.0/16 
iptables -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE 
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

With these rules everything works fine, however, even DHCP fails

```
# restrict eth2
iptables -i eth2 -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -i eth2 -A FORWARD -j DROP
iptables -i eth2 -A INPUT -p udp --dport 67:68 --sport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
iptables -i eth2 -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -i eth2 -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -i eth2 -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -i eth2 -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -i eth2 -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -i eth2 -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 --dst 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 --src 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 --dst 2.3.4.5 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 --src 2.3.4.5 -j ACCEPT
```

Where's my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If statements with "-j DROP" go early in the configuration they are not giving a chance to process statements with "-j ACCEPT". Move them to the end.